# In regard to the structure of 余裕のある自分が嫌になります

Tags: grammar, parsing

Here is a sentence taken from a song written by 宇多田ヒカル

> 余裕のある自分が嫌になります

It looks like I can conjure up 2 ways of dissecting the first part of it.

余裕の/ある --

余裕/の/ある自分 -- this way ある seems to be redundant.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

心の損得を考える余裕のある自分 contains a relative clause as shown below:

> 自分には心の損得を考える余裕がある。
> I have the capacity to think about mental profit and loss.
>
> ▼ (relative clause)
>
> 心の損得を考える余裕がある自分
>
> ▼ (ga-no conversion)
>
> 心の損得を考える余裕**の**ある自分
> I, the one who has the capacity to think about mental profit and loss

This ある is a verb meaning "to exist". So this person doesn't like how she herself has been thinking about whether this love is beneficial or not.